# Is it possible to fade-in fade-out by selecting the text of radiobutton in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi Is it possible to do fade-in and fade-out by selecting the text of radio buttons . I will explain my issue clearly.

**My Radio Buttons**

I have two radio buttons in Visit Type.

[image]

**Fade-in Fade-out Fields**

[image]

If i select **Visit Type** as **Direct Visit** it will show **StartTime** and **EndTime** otherwise it wont show these two fields. Now all are working fine. Now what i want is i  want to show the fields also by selecting the text of radio button

**Selecting Text**
[image]

That is if i go and click over on text (that is Direct Visit not inside of radio button circle)it automatically select in inside of circle and have to show the fields (Start Time and EndTime). I tried to explain my issue as per my level best . please any one tell me it is possible to show the fields depend upon by selecting the radio button text in mvc4

**My View Code**

```
   <div class="col-sm-4" id="VisitType">
   <div class="form-group">
   <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
   @Html.Label("Visit Type", new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.VisitType, "true", new { id = "" }) Telephone
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.VisitType, "false", new { id = "" }) Direct Visit

   </div>
   </div>

  <div id="StartTime">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="form-group">
   @Html.Label("Start Time", new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control ", type = "text" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("End Time", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndTime, new { @class = "form-control ", type = "text" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime)
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

**My J-query code**

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#StartTime').hide();
            $('#VisitType input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() === 'false') {
                    $('#StartTime').show();
                }
                else 
                {
                    $('#StartTime').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have to enclose the radio button within the label. Try this out!

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="VisitType">
           <div class="form-group">
           <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
           <label>
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.VisitType, "true", new { id = "" }) 
    Telephone
     </label>
    <label>
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.VisitType, "false", new { id = "" }) 
    Direct Visit
        </label>
           </div>
           </div>
```

You can also use label instead of span.

Comment: Ok susan. If my piece of code exactly helped you out then please accept & vote!

Comment: Happy Coding Susan ;) !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know asp.net. But I understand what you want is. So, I just only give you idea. In HTML, you can used like this.

```
Visit Type
<label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
<input type="radio" id="telephone">
```

Now, if you click Telephone label not radio button directly, the radio button is automatically selected without clicking that button.

I hope this solution will help you.